# I am new to QAF. I m using common steps to assert/verify text

Tags: qaf

Error-expected " 2,438.16" to match glob " 2,438.16" (had transformed the glob into regexp " 2,438.16"

```
assertText("//*[@id='tv_balance']"," 2,438.16");
verifyText("//*[@id='tv_balance']"," 2,438.16");
```

I tried both method assertText and verifyText in qaf but in expected value special character \ is getting passed because of which my test case is getting failed. kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided details about assert/verifyText method, from which class you are referring. If it is from common steps, you can provide `exact:` prefix for exact match. For example:

```
assertText("//*[@id='tv_balance']","exact:2,438.16");
verifyText("//*[@id='tv_balance']","exact:2,438.16");
```

It also supports `start:`,`end:`, `in:`, `regex:`, `regexpi:` prefix, default is `glob:`.